# how to delete every alternate row in access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a huge access table containing about 400000 rows . what sql query can i give to delete every alternate row in the table. ?

I do have a column in the table which has values from 1 , 2, 3 ,4 .... about 400000 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Mod`. Something like

```
DELETE Table1.*
FROM Table1
WHERE ((([ID] Mod 2)=0));
```

Comment: Access sticks in those parentheses, but it does not need them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table's name is "table", and your column with the line number is named "id", it would be

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE MOD(id,2)=0
```

**Edit:** Apparently, this is the wrong Syntax for MS Access. Use astanders solution below.

Comment: I do not see why this is the accepted answer when the syntax is wrong.

Comment: yes i had given it as right answer earlier because i tried on mysql and it did worked good.