# Delete Every Alternate Row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to clean up a table which has three columns, ID (uniqueidentifier), Observation (nvarchar), and Timestamp (datetimeoffset). The content is generated by two sensors at 1 hour interval, and the value of Observation is the same from the two sensors. My idea is to do a SELECT query such as

```
SELECT * FROM [Records] ORDER BY [Timestamp]
```

and then delete every alternate row.

I found this on SO [how to delete every alternate row in access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361466/how-to-delete-every-alternate-row-in-access-table), but doesn't really applies here as the ID is not Int but UID.

A sample of the data would look like:

[image]

Comment: is the `timestamp` exactely equal for those duplicate rows?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later you can do something like this.

```
delete T
from (
       select row_number() over(order by [Timestamp]) as rn
       from YourTable
       where SomeColumn = @SomeValue
     ) T
where T.rn % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Yes I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2. Is it possible to add a WHERE clause for the SELECT? Such as

delete T 
from ( 
       select row_number() over(order by [DateTime]) as rn 
       from [Records] WHERE [Timestamp] < '2012/6/30 12:00am'
     ) T 
where T.rn % 2 = 0

Comment: @Jim Sure. You do it in the inner query. I have added a sample where clause to the query.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of deleting alternate records you might use safer variation - delete only duplicate Observations, so that in case of error in data you don't fall out of sync:

```
; with cte as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by Observation 
                            order by [Timestamp]) rn
    from [Records]
)
delete cte
 where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you could use a CTE, with row_number() to generate effectively a temp numeric id column. Then the same idea could be applied - delete where a row number mod 2 is 0:

```
;WITH temp
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) rn
         FROM   [Records]
         ORDER  BY [Timestamp])
DELETE FROM temp
WHERE  rn % 2 = 0
```

Comment: FYI CTEs are only available if you're using SQL Server 2005 or later - you didn't specify the version in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so using the MOD operator which divide two numbers and return the remainder

try

```
DELETE FROM [Records] WHERE ([ID] Mod 2)=0)
```

put it inside a loop to delete all alternate rows

so for example

```
ID = 0;
rows = get_number_of_rows_in_the_table;
i = 0; // counter
while(i<rows) {
ID = get the ID of row 0
if(ID MOD 2 = 0) {
//perform delete operation
DELETE FROM [Records] WHERE ID=the ID you just got;
} else { 
increment the counter 
i++
}
```

this is one solution but not a correct syntax for access
hope it helps

Comment: Don't loop if you can avoid it. There are more efficient ways to do things in SQL.

Comment: @loophole there was no need for the down vote! this is 6 years old and your comment is meaningless. show a better way rather than down voting an actual solution regardless if you like it or no it is going to still be a solution