# How to delete rows in SQL table if column contains even number in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to SQL and I am using windows forms.

I have `table1` in SQL server which contains 10 columns one column named `Sale_ID` (Int). This table has 1000 rows and I want to delete all rows which their `Sale_ID` contains an even number.

For example something like:

`"Delete from Table1 where Sale_ID is even number"`

Following code deletes rows from `Table1` but I do not know how to add "even" clause (if there is one):

```
MyConnection.Open();
MyCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Sale_ID =....?";

MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

MyConnection.Close();
```

Anyone knows how to modify the code so I can delete all rows which their Sale_ID is an even number? . please help , thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Every Alternate Row in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931060/delete-every-alternate-row-in-sql)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need this requirement, but look into using the `mod` or `%` operator.  Depends on the database you are using though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using modulo division, i.e. `DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Sale_ID % 2 = 0`

Comment: and "WHERE Sale_ID % 2 != 0" deletes odd numbers? yeah?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Delete from Table1 where Sale_ID % 2 = 0
```

Comment: and "WHERE Sale_ID % 2 != 0" deletes odd numbers? yeah?